# Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm getting a Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric. In my stored
procedure although only when it has to make the calculations. Here is my code, I'm using a convert still seems to be something wrong.

```
set @Text = @Text + 'Something:' + 
(select case when s.ATF = '' then '0' 
else Convert(varchar,100 *((s.ATF *1.00) /     
(s.Total * 1.00))) + '%' 
end 
from Maintenance.dbo.stats s 
where s.ID = @ID) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
```

Thanx!

Comment: You need to supply the types of fields and parameters. My guess: s.ID is varchar and @ID is numeric.

Comment: Actually @ID variable is declared as a varchar, it works when the case when returns a '0' feels like it cannot get the calculation correct

Comment: @andrejcurcic what is the datatype of `s.ATF` ?

Comment: What datatype is s.ATF?  You compare it to '', but you also do s.ATF * 1.00.  Also when converting to VARCHAR, you need to specify the length, i.e. CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), ...).

Comment: Yes, they are both varchar(50) though SQL tries to convert it from varchar to numeric?

Comment: I have to use the 1.00 otherwise it will fail to make the division

Comment: What are the values of `s.ATF`?

Comment: it's 1 and the other one 442 so I divide 60.5 / 442 * 100 to get the  % that is why I + '%' at the end of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you take a `varchar` and multiply it by a numeric value. That forces an implicit conversion to a numeric type. You should specify conversion explicitly. I chose `decimal(38,6)` but you can change that.

```
set @Text = @Text + 'Something:' + 
(select case when s.ATF = '' then '0' 
else Convert(varchar, 100 * cast(s.ATF as decimal(38,6)) /     
cast(s.Total as decimal(38,6))) + '%' 
end 
from Maintenance.dbo.stats s 
where s.ID = @ID) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
```

You can see how this wrong conversion works on that simple example:

```
declare @x as varchar(50) = '11'
select @x * 1.00
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to remove one more `1.00`, updated it now.